# keep getting OPTIONS net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on angular 2 HTTP GET when sending Bearer token

Tags: http, angular

I am getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when trying to access protected resource. on not protected it works fine. when I use tools like Postman or Paw and provide bearer token it works. So it looks like smth with angular http but I am not sure what exactly and what do I need to do with it. Any ideas?!